# onItemClickListener in ListView not working

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-listfragment, onitemclicklistener

I have a `ListView` within a `ListFragment`, and currently I just want a click on any of the items to go to `ProblemActivity.class`, which is currently a barebones 'HelloWorld' activity. Problem is I don't think the onItemClickListener is firing, and I'm not sure why, as I'm an Android novice. Any ideas?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below).
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return MainFragment.newInstance(position);
        case 1:
            return ProfileFragment.newInstance(position);
        case 2:
            return ReferenceFragment.newInstance(position);
        default:
            return MainFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * The default fragment containing a list view of problems.
 */
public static class MainFragment extends ListFragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static MainFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public MainFragment() {
    }

    static final String[] PROBLEMS = new String[] { "Problem 1", "Problem 2", "Probelm 3",
        "Problem 4", "Problem 5", "Problem 6", "Problem 7", "Problem 8",
        "Problem 9" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        /*TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));*/
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_probs,PROBLEMS));

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView
                .findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainFragment.this.getActivity(), ProblemActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}

/**
 * The profile fragment. To be completed later.
 */
public static class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static ProfileFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        ProfileFragment fragment = new ProfileFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ProfileFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container,
                false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}   

/**
 * The reference fragment. To be completed later.
 */
public static class ReferenceFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static ReferenceFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        ReferenceFragment fragment = new ReferenceFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ReferenceFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reference, container,
                false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}   

}
```

list_probs.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: Post your `list_prob.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to

```
ListView listView = getListView();
```

**EDIT**

Add below code after `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_probs,PROBLEMS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainFragment.this.getActivity(), ProblemActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hmm...this caused the program to crash and throw a 'Content view not yet created` exception.

Comment: @user2060659 I edited see it . add that code after `onCreateView`.

Comment: Okay, it works now. Can you explain why this code has to be in the onActivityCreated method?

Comment: @user2060659 `getListView()` is getting listview after creating view but `onActivityCreated` will called after view.

Answer (score 1):

Apart for the other answer you directly add `ListItem click` event like

```
 @Override  
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {  
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), PROBLEMS[(int) id],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
}
```

For example go to

- [DemonstrationofusingListFragmenttoshowalistofitemsfromacannedarray.](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/DemonstrationofusingListFragmenttoshowalistofitemsfromacannedarray.htm)
- [android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/android-custom-adapter-listview-with-listfragment-and-loadermanager-inside-fragmentactivity/)

Comment: You mean, add that method to the ListFragment class?

Comment: @user2060659 yup take a look in my example links

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. Any idea why the `clickListener` doesn't work, even when I follow the suggestion the other post made?

Comment: @user2060659 if you used `ListFragment` then you directly override this method .No need to implement it separately.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Add this property in your adapter layout `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` listener of `Listview` starts working.